# Bulk email using ASP.Net 4 and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I need send bulk email using ASP.Net 4 and c# to the registered users on our web page to facilitate access on our products and services.

The tutorial is: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/47548d/how-to-send-bulk-email-using-Asp-Net/

In the table users testing I have now two email:

1. firstEmail@domain.com
2. secondEmail@domain.com

In this testing I don't have error, because email and password are correct for single user, but I have two problems.

**Problem #1**

1. will receiving three email messages:

   **First message:**
   From: account@domain.com
   To: firstEmail@domain.com

   **Second message:**
   From: account@domain.com
   To: firstEmail@domain.com, secondEmail@domain.com

   **Third message:**
   From: account@domain.com
   To: firstEmail@domain.com, secondEmail@domain.com

I need one message for single user:

```
First message:    
From: account@domain.com    
To: firstEmail@domain.com

Second message:    
From: account@domain.com    
To: secondEmail@domain.com
```

**Problem #2**

How to set a time between sending the first message and the next message?

I used this lines in code behind:

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
        {
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(); 

            lbltotalcount.Text = string.Empty;

            foreach (GridViewRow grow in grvCustomers.Rows)
            {
                try
                {
                    email = grow.Cells[0].Text.Trim();
                    password = grow.Cells[1].Text.Trim();

                    to = email.ToString();
                    from = "account@domain.com";

                    mailMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(from);
                    mailMessage.To.Add(to);
                    mailMessage.Subject = "Test send email";

                    Body = "";
                    Body += '\n' + "<b>Email: </b>";
                    Body += '\n' + "<br>  " + email.ToString() + "<br>";
                    Body += '\n' + "<b>Password: </b>";
                    Body += '\n' + "<br>  " + password.ToString() + "<br><br>";

                    mailMessage.Body = Body;
                    mailMessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

                    smtpClient.Host = "localhost";
                    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);                        

                    Response.Write("<br />" + mailMessage.Body.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex.Message);
                }
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: One suggestion is to use local variables inside the try/catch block for `email`, `password`, `to`, `from`, and `mailMessage`. Also, what SMTP host are you using? Are you certain that you are not receiving emails from previous tests? Some free SMTP hosts are slow (like gmail).

Comment: I use SMTP of my provider is efficient service. I'm sorry but I don't understand your suggestion on use local variables.

Comment: Use a console app to send the emails and introduce a pause between batches of 100 or so.

Comment: Okay the second problem is solved, but for first problem any idea?

Comment: One suggestion is to _not_ use any try/catch blocks at all. Especially when throwing away the inner exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

By question 1 you mean you don't want to generate the message twice when sending to two email addresses??

If so you can abstract out the message logic to a method and pass the email address to the method So it will be like

inside click btnSend_Click event

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
        {
            ...ALL THE PREVIOUS CODE...

                        mailMessage.Body = GenerateMessage(email);
                        mailMessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

           ... REST OF THE CODE
        }
    catch()
    {}
 }

    private string GenerateMessage(string email)
    {
       var sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.Append("<b>Email: </b>");
       sb.Append(string.Format("<br> {0} <br>",email));
       //.
       //.Rest of the stuff here
       //..
       return sb.ToString();
    }
```

**------------------- UPDATED------------**

```
public class Message
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var messages = new List<Message>();
        foreach (var grow in grvCustomers.Rows)
        {
            //by theway putting password like this in grid is a bad idea
            var email = grow.Cells[0].Text.Trim();
            var pwd = grow.Cells[1].Text.Trim();
            SendEmail(new Message { email = email, password = pwd });
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }

    lbltotalcount.Text = string.Empty;
}

private void SendEmail(Message message)
{
    using (var smtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient())
    {
        using (var mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage())
        {
                mailMessage.Subject = "Test send email";
                mailMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("account@domain.com");
                mailMessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailMessage.Body = GenerateMessage(message);
                mailMessage.To.Add(message.email);
                smtpClient.Host = "localhost";
                smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
            }
        }
    }

private string GenerateMessage(Message message)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<b>Email: </b>");
    sb.Append(string.Format("<br> {0} <br>", message.email));
    sb.Append("<br>  " + message.password + "<br><br>");
    //.
    //.Rest of the stuff here
    //..
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

}

Comment: I need to avoid to append e-mail address in the recipient... in this moment I don't have one message one recipient, I have one message multiple recipient....

Comment: you want those passwords to go to all the recipients??? or you are trying to send email with password for each recipient? I just updated the answer hope that's what you trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind you need empty the list of address in the foreach.

Try this,

```
mailMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(from);
mailMessage.To.Clear(); //empty list of address
mailMessage.To.Add(to);
mailMessage.Subject = "Test send email";
```

You can read about it here Object MailAddressCollection:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.net.mail.mailaddresscollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Hope I helped you.